# $.widget is not a function when loading a homepage after add custom jQuery on custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, jquery

`$.widget` is not a function when loading a homepage after add custom jQuery on custom theme.

I have define my custom jQuery javascript library on my theme header under

```
Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

The js error message

> `$.wedget is not a function`

which occur when loading homepage sometime ....[not 100% occur].

Is about js definition location problem? please help.

For example one of my jQuery source code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = jQuery('.page-header'),
      scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); 
  if (scroll >= 30) sticky.addClass('fixed'), jQuery('.panel.header').hide(),jQuery('.page-header').css('border-bottom','1px solid #efefef');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed'),jQuery('.panel.header').show(),jQuery('.page-header').css('border-bottom','none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check `jQuery` is working or not using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert('jquery working');
        // your code goes here.
    });

});
</script>
```

If it's work then put your code inside this code section.Also load your js file after `jQuery` library.

Comment: Related tip. You should add `domReady!` as a dependency if you need your code to fire on page load. Otherwise other plugins are not aware of the dom ready dependency. See this question for more info - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166126/how-use-requiredjs-to-execute-the-js-after-the-dom-ready

Answer (score 0):

- Include Jquery library before calling this script.
- Or, try use your script at footer after all Jquery and JS libraries loaded. (Just for testing)
- Wrap your function inside 
  `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  //your script
  });`
- I believe your script is being executed before other jQuery libraries have been loaded properly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks your response. My custom code is working fine. it is call after jQuery definition. but original Magento javascript prompt error when loading homepage '$.widget'. I guesses is about conflict with my custom js on my theme design.

Comment: I find a example is define requirejs-config.js on my theme to define own jQuery execute point......but I studied on it....

Comment: Please use jQuery library that comes with the theme. Remove any other jQuery libraries calling from page.xml. This might be the issue of jQuery conflict