# How to use RequiredJS to execute the JS after the DOM ready?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I'd like to execute my JS after the DOM ready using RequiredJS instead of this:

```
$(window).load()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this feature of the [RequiredJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) **'domReady!'** like the native Magento's modules use:

**PHTML**

```
<script>
        require(['jquery','domReady!'], function ($) {
            // Your Code
        });
</script>
```

**Or JS**

```
define(['jquery','domReady!'], function($) {

    // Your Code

    }(jQuery)
);
```

Comment: It's correct but "domRedy" is not a method but a RequireJS module. See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload

Comment: Using `domReady!` gives exception