# Custom JS is not include undefined error magento 2

Tags: javascript, error, undefined

`requirejs-config.js file path is`Codility/Customers/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` and  **code is**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'customhighcharts': 'Codility_Dashboard/js/customhighcharts'
},
    shim: {
        'customhighcharts': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
}
};
```

my js file path is `code/Codility/Customers/view/frontend/web/js/customhighcharts.js`

`customhighcharts` file code taken from `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js` link

My **phtml** file path is `code/Codility/Customers/view/frontend/templates/Seller/navigation.phtml` and **code is**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "customhighcharts",
        "domReady!"
    ], function ($, customhighcharts) {
        customhighcharts.chart('container', {
            title: {
                text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Employees'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    label: {
                        connectorAllowed: false
                    },
                    pointStart: 2010
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Installation',
                data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
            }, {
                name: 'Manufacturing',
                data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
            }, {
                name: 'Sales & Distribution',
                data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
            }, {
                name: 'Project Development',
                data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
            }],
            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        });
    });
</script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Graph is not shown and **Error in console is**

**TypeError: customhighcharts is undefined**

Comment: Do you see the code from your requirejs-config.js in MagentoROOT/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js ? If not you can delete this file and reload your page.

Comment: Yes Exactly in  `MagentoROOT/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js ?` file my customhighcharts is exist

Comment: I have no idea in that case

Comment: What if you use define in js ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166126/how-use-requiredjs-to-execute-the-js-after-the-dom-ready

Comment: i don't think i use <script>// <![CDATA[
        require([
            'jquery',
            'domReady!'
        ], function ($) {
            // Your Code
        });
        // ]]>
</script> 
then also use `define` in js

Comment: @BartZalas

i am not write js just download from `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js`
then how use define there

Comment: Have you get the solution?

Comment: Yes ! resolved . . .

Comment: How ,,Can you add it as an Answer?

Answer (score 0):

The above share code **having js file path issue**

**requirejs-config.js** file path is `Codility/Customers/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` and code is

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'customhighcharts': 'Codility_Dashboard/js/customhighcharts'
...
```

and js file path is `code/Codility/Customers/view/frontend/web/js/customhighcharts.js`

so in **requirejs-config.js** instead of **Codility_Dashboard** it should be **Codility_Customers**

```
var config = {
        paths: {
                'customhighcharts': 'Codility_Customers/js/customhighcharts'
    ...
```

Hope this given solution will solve your concerns.