# Add custom javascript after js components load

Tags: javascript, uicomponent, magento2.4, requirejs

I'm still a novice when it comes to Magento 2 frontend with jsLayout, requireJS, etc. I have a custom module where, in javascript, I am trying to attach an onchange listener to the email textbox. I tried going the simple route by including a .phtml file via layout.xml:

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sf.checkout.trackuser" as="sf.checkout.trackuser"
          after="sf.ads.default" template="MyVendor_SF::checkout-track-user.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

checkout-track-user.phtml

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input#customer-email").on("change", function(e) {
            //console.log('yay');
        });
    });
});
```

However, when my js runs, the `input#customer-email` element is not yet loaded on the page, even when put inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`. How can run my js code after this textbox has loaded on the page?

My guess is that I need to add a component to the checkout jsLayout, but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I've looked at docs and examples, and currently, I have:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sf.checkout.trackuser" as="sf.checkout.trackuser"
               after="sf.ads.default" template="MyVendor_SF::checkout-track-user.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_SF/js/track-checkout-guest</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

I have no clue how I would code `track-checkout-guest.js` though.. in my case I don't think it's an actual component (no .html template or knockoutJS involved), so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: It's kinda hack but you can try checking if your element exists then run function. In jquery you can do this by `if($("#customer-email").length)` and then put your code inside if. Maybe that could solve it

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166126/how-to-use-requiredjs-to-execute-the-js-after-the-dom-ready/166127

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your solution doesn't work is that e-mail component appears in DOM after DOM is "ready". You could either create a Magento JS mixin for the component and run your code after the component is initialized (see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html), or use your approach but with MutationObserver instead of document ready event (see: https://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object).